# WCF - reading an xml file in a service using XElement.Load

Tags: wcf, load, xelement

i have a simple xml file in a wcf service that i am trying to load using Xelement.Load("sample.xml") which is not reading the file. What's the right way of doing this?

The service is supposed to return an xml to an asp.net application.

TIA

Comment: what error (if any) are you getting? is the problem reading the file on the server side?? Are you sure you're reading frmo the right location? Does your service has permission to read from that location?? or is the problem passing back that string to the caller - please clarify!

Comment: @marc_s: the service in wcf throws 'FileNotFoundException'. The xml file is located in wcfservicelibrary1 project root & trying to load from file Service1.cs

Comment: check your paths, and permissions.

Comment: @Cheeso - how do we pass the correct path to the load method? i couldn't even code for server.mappath, what am i missing?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.  maybe if you showed some code, we'd be able to offer some better insight.

Comment: @Cheeso - this code throws the error.
XElement _x = XElement.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

i tried to do XElement.Load(Server.Mappath("XMLFile1.xml")); but this was not possible.

Comment: Better to post the code in the question.  Also - Server.MapPath is not found in a WCF service, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by providing the ABSOLUTE path as the parameter to the XElement.Load() method, RELATIVE path would be better though.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this then.

`var appPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
 bodyFile = Path.Combine(appPath, @"<File Name Path");`

This will work relative to your application's physical path.